# Adding commas in Bibtex using Jabref

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

I'm finally coming to the point where I add my references.

I'm using Jabref to create them.

The result of one of them looks as follows:

[image]

However, I had like it to print commas instead of dots:

[image]

Also, In some references, Jabref adds "`In:`":

[image]

How can I edit those things in Jabref?

Thank you!

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ at present? Or do you use `biblatex` (and, if so, with which options do you load `biblatex`)?

Comment: Can you please explain what it means employ at present? You mean when I use it In my .tex file? I use Bib(la)Tex.

Comment: I mean, is there a `\bibliographystyle` instruction or a `\usepackage{biblatex}` instruction in your tex file? Off-topic: the author's surname is spelled "Luenberger", not "Leunberger".

Comment: Only thing I have is :\printbibliography[heading=none] and \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

Comment: So, just to clear up some confusion: Jabref does *not* create the formatted bibliography. Rather, it's `biblatex` (and the `biber` utility). I suggest you search this site for biblatex postings which show you how to (a) suppress the `In: ` prefix string and (b) use commas rather than periods as dividers between blocks. So what does Jabref do? It assembles the bibliographic entries are places them into a bib file, for further processing by LaTeX and the biblatex package.